# Remove characters from HTTP response

Tags: php, http, request

in my api system when the result is showed in plaintext, it looks like: 
`"the result\n"`

i need to remove those `" \n"` and the result should contain just `the result`.

i set `header('Content-type: text/plain');` for the result.

btw. my system is in PHP

UPDATE:

when i open the url in the browser it gives me `the result` but when i test the request with http://hurl.it the result is `"the result\n"`

i tried with `trim` and `rtrim` but didn't help

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where do you want the characters removed? In the source or when receiving? If the latter, why not use `str_replace()`?

Comment: in the source. in the code i'm echoing just `the result` but later it's shown as `"the result\n"`

Comment: Find the code that outputs the characters you don't want (we can't, you haven't shared that code … or any code beyond the call to `header`) and change it.

Comment: To clarify, are you seeing the literal `\n` characters or extra whitespace at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove any leading and trailing whitespace with [trim()](http://php.net/trim).

```
$string = trim($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to go through your code and see if there are any whitespace characters before or after `<?` or `?>`.

Or else, you could use output buffering.

Use at the absolute top of your code:

```
@ob_start();
```

And at absolute the bottom:

```
die(trim(@ob_get_clean()));
```

Comment: It's probably a trailing space. (It could be a leading space if you are including a file after you are print the output, but that's probably less likely.) Anyway, you should fix the problem at the source, and not use trimming the output buffer as a work around.

Comment: I totally agree! You should never do work-arounds. But in those cases where there are 100's of files involved. It ain't always that fun. But if that's the case. I would suggest that he used GREP on those files. Using GREP he would find the files in no time. (\s*<\?|\?>\s*) should work fairly good I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why this may happen, but a common one is the use of magic_quotes.

Are you able to check if magic quotes are switched on, and maybe turn them off if they are?
You can read about magic quotes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Alternatively, you can try using the [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) command.